# ReactJS: Map and Find

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Introduction

I have a search filter in which I enter parameters such as sender and recipient.

In this way for the sender I make a call and get results.
For the recipient I make another call and get other results.

So I will have two arrays:

> sent

> sent1

what I would like to do is iterate through the first arrival comparing each element with each element of the second array and if a certain condition is exceeded save the element of the first array.

Now my Code is:

```
let filteredSent = {rows: []}
sent.rows.map( (elem) => { sent1.rows.find( (value) => { 
          if(value.key[2] === values.recipient.Code && value.key[0] === "RECIPIENT" && elem.key[1] === value.key[1] && elem.key[3] === value.key[3] && elem.value === value.value){
            filteredSent.rows.push(elem)
          }
      })
    } )
```

where `values.recipient.Code` is an input value that I choose from a list.
My problem is that I make this comparison, but I find myself certain results that shouldn't be there.

Is what I'm doing the map and find a wrong use?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You need to `return` within a `map`.  Otherwise you should just use `forEach`.

Comment: And I should return the `filteredSent`?